# dpdk-pdump "no driver found for net_pcap_rx_0"

Tags: dpdk

Ubuntu 16, DPDK 16

I have a couple of DPDK-based applications sending packets between two machines and want to capture them with `dpdk-pdump`. I'm running it with `sudo ./build/app/pdump/dpdk-pdump -c 0x00f -- --pdump 'port=0,queue=*,rx-dev=/tmp/rx.pcap'`, and I see this output and a crash:

`EAL: no driver found for eth_pcap_rx_0
EAL: Driver, cannot attach the device
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
Cause: vdev creation failed:create_mp_ring_vdev:736`

My DPDK was compiled like this: `hostname:~/dpdk-stable-16.07.1/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc# CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_PCAP=y make` (also did `export CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_PCAP=y` before) so that it builds with libpcap support, as the documentation said to do. And my system has libpcap installed. The make script output shows `== Build lib/librte_pdump`. Looking around online, I've only found [one person with a similar issue](http://dpdk.org/ml/archives/users/2016-March/000356.html), and the suggested fix was what I tried. Is there something else I have to do?

I tried installing the [DPDK Ubuntu package's version of the tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man1/dpdk-pdump.1.html) and using the `dpdk-pdump` command, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, setting CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_PCAP=y in command line does not work, so the compiled dpdk-pdump have no pcap support.

In config/common_base set CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_PCAP=y, remove your build directory and recompile the DPDK.

Make sure the .config file you your build directory has CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_PCAP=y

Comment: Ah, I thought the documentation was talking about environmental variables. Had me going in circles. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also if you get following error:

```
Error: missing pcap.h
rte_eth_pcap.c:19:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
```

while compiling with option `CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_PCAP=y`

Install libpcap-dev* package. Eg:

```
yum install libpcap-devel
```